# Loading android studio project fails on step Download gradle-8.0-bin-zip with Read timed out error

Tags: android-studio

I wanted to follow the beginner tutorial for Java android development on a Windows 10 laptop and after successfully installing android studio, creating a "Hello World" project and opening it. Indexing runs fine, then when gradle starts to sync it stops at "Download gradle-8.0-bin-zip" and after 1 min 41 seconds it fails with "Read timed out" error.

I've tried to solve it for an hour but couldn't find any solutions that worked. I suspect that somehow gradle wasn't able to install with android studio and thus android studio is unable to sync, maybe. I've tried to download gradle separately. But the download time was extremely large. Checked if there is some kind of server issue, but it seems to be fine (btw I have no issues with my internet connection, 290Mbps but the gradle site seems to be slow for me).

Answer (score 0):

- Try to check Gradle in `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment  > Build Tools > Gradle`. Then look for `Gradle home` in `Gradle settings`. Change that URL with another distribution URL.
- Maybe you should look in `gradle.properties` and add this:

```
    org.gradle.configureondemand=false
    org.gradle.daemon=true
    org.gradle.parallel=true
    org.gradle.caching=true
    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
```

Comment: If this doesn't work try to reinstall Android Studio and find about that version on the official webpage.